# See profile other users in FOSUserBundle

Tags: fosuserbundle, symfony-3.4

first, sorry for my english .

I have a site with an ad system. 
Thanks to FOSUserBundle, access to his profile is very simple. 
But I would like to make the profile of other users public. 
Let me explain, I would like us to click on the name of a user to see his profile. 
When I dump users, I have two distinct users : 
app.user that returns the current user and ad.user that returns the user who wrote the ad. 
Unfortunately when I click the user who created the ad, it automatically sends to the profile of the current user :'(

I looked for a lot of solutions but nothing works, the ad.user continues to return the current user despite a url that indicates the id of the author of the ad.

I am on symfony 3. Please help me.

Dump of app.user =

```
User {#405 ▼

#id: 1

#ville: "Angers"

#description: "Test description dans profil Modifé TEST 2!!"

  -ads: PersistentCollection {#450 ▶}
  -comments: PersistentCollection {#475 ▶}

#username: "superadmin"

#usernameCanonical: "superadmin"

#email: "superadmin@gmail.com"

#emailCanonical: "superadmin@gmail.com"

#enabled: true

#salt: null

#password: "$2y$13$lSKxx9k4ctd5BNBDEoCEGeHU1jHi7S8jD7o8jS01S1TNX/KK8.zH."

#plainPassword: null

#lastLogin: DateTime @1525031449 {#400 ▶}

#confirmationToken: null

#passwordRequestedAt: null

#groups: null

#roles: array:1 [▶]
```

}

Dump of ad.user =

```
User {#740 ▼
+__isInitialized__: true

#id: 2

#ville: "Angers"

#description: null
  -ads: PersistentCollection {#1057 ▶}
  -comments: PersistentCollection {#1074 ▶}

#username: "usertest"

#usernameCanonical: "usertest"

#email: "usertest@gmail.com"

#emailCanonical: "usertest@gmail.com"

#enabled: true

#salt: null

#password: "$2y$13$3RhGWDCHt/uQn2EvLhuQ0es8dNOuwXhgiU/gtRKc3CzhQ7iWB.VUm"

#plainPassword: null

#lastLogin: DateTime @1525008711 {#1048 ▶}

#confirmationToken: null

#passwordRequestedAt: null

#groups: null

#roles: [] …2
```

}

Is it possible that there is a priority somewhere that forces access to the profile of the current user ?

My code in twig :

```
<a href="{{ path('fos_user_profile_show', {'id': ad.user.id }) }}">Publiée par : {{ ad.user.username}} <span class="text-secondary">le {{ ad.date|date("d/m/Y") }}</span></a>
```

Thank you

Comment: He misses the hello at the beginning of the message :D

Answer (score 1):

I FOUND !!!!!!

in ProfileController i add a new showIdAction:

```
    /**
 * @Route("/profile/{id}", name="profile_id", requirements={"id"="\d+"})
 */
public function showIdAction($id)
{
    $user = $this->getDoctrine()
        ->getRepository('AppBundle:User')
        ->find($id);
    if (!is_object($user) || !$user instanceof UserInterface) {
        throw new AccessDeniedException('This user does not have access to this section.');
    }

    return $this->render('@FOSUser/Profile/show.html.twig', array(
        'user' => $user,
    ));
}
```

And, in profile.xml ( routing of FOSUserBundle) i add a new route:

```
    <route id="profile_id" path="/{id}" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">fos_user.profile.controller:showIdAction</default>
</route>
```

In twig :

```
<a href="{{ path('profile_id', {'id': ad.user.id }) }}
```

And its WORK .

I leave here the question if ever others seek a solution